# (401) Unauthorized Error When Calling Web API from a Console Application

Tags: asp.net-web-api

When I call my WEB API from my Console Application, I encounter:

**The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.**

This application runs in Interanet (**Windows Authentication**)

```
            Uri uri = new Uri("http://myServer/api/main/foo");
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            client.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

            using (Stream data = client.OpenRead(uri))
            {
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(data))
                {
                    string result = sr.ReadToEnd();
                    Console.WriteLine(result);
                }
            }
```

**Updated**

If I replace

> client.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

with this line

> client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential( username, password);

it works fine but I need the current credential to be set automatically.

Any idea? 
Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 2):

You use the default  windows credentials here

```
client.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```

Specify the credential that you want to authenticate using the following code:

```
var credential = new NetworkCredential(, , );

serverReport.ReportServerCredentials.NetworkCredentials = credential;
```

Comment: Thanks for taking your time, Actually I am using  Windows Authentication

Answer (score 0):

following line is the cause of this behaviour :

```
client.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```

Actually this line assigns the credentials of the logged in user or the user being impersonated ( which is only possible in web applications ) , so what I believe is that you have to provide credentials explicitly (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.credentialcache(v=vs.110).aspx) , thanks.